# index does not get used when there is "OR" in the query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have an index on the `check_timestamp` column, the index gets used by the following query

```
... where check_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' ORDER BY  check_timestamp  NULLS FIRST LIMIT 10
```

But the index does not get used with the following query

```
... where (check_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' OR check_timestamp IS NULL) ORDER BY check_timestamp  NULLS FIRST LIMIT 10
```

Why is this happening? any way around it?

Below is the database schema

```
id  uuid [gen_random_uuid()]    
street_db   text    
check_timestamp timestamptz NULL    
last_accessed   timestamptz NULL    
website text    
street  text    
in_use  boolean [false] 
zipcode_db_id   uuid NULL
```

Comment: Add the whole query please and the table definition.

Comment: PG has expression [indexes]( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-expressional.html). The problem is that they won't work with an expression like `NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'` (not [`IMMUTABLE`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8b425db88c3845134751da42ea0a6892)). You could perhaps schedule a job to run at 00:01 every night and index a column which just has the date from 30 days ago - a bit of a hack, but it might do the job? Generated columns might help (immutable problem again?), but they won't be available till release [12](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1943/).

Comment: @Vérace I did some tests, the index does not get used if I have `check_timestamp IS NULL`, but it does get used when I have `check_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'`

Comment: For this type of query it's better to not have NULL values in the column (precisely because of non-efficient plans). To indicate "no end" in a timestamp column you can alternatively store the value `'infinity'` instead of NULL. `update the_table set check_timestamp = 'infinity' where check_timestamp is null;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did more testing and I found another major slow down was caused by `ORDER BY check_timestamp  NULLS FIRST` I then recreated the index with nulls first and it fixed the performance issues. Now it uses the index

Answer (score 2):

In general PostgreSQL is capable of using an index in this situation.  It can scan the index two times and combine them with a BitmapOr.

The reason it cannot or has chosen not to do this in your particular case would depend on the particulars of your case, which you are not sharing with us.  Perhaps it just thinks the alternative plan will be cheaper.

Comment: I did some tests, the index does not get used if I have `check_timestamp IS NULL`, but it does get used when I have `check_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'` the index is not being used for checking NULL

Comment: I've also done some tests.  The index does get used to test NULLs **in general**.  If you want me to test your particulars, you will have to share them.

Comment: I have added the database schema

Comment: I think what is causing the performance issue is `ORDER BY check_timestamp  NULLS FIRST` right?

Comment: creating the index with putting NULLS first fixed the performance issue